# Creating a rails record with string value for integer sets nil silently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my rails (4.2.1) app, I have a `Post` model with an integer field `foo`. While creating a post, I passed a string to the integer field. I expected an error, but the record got created with `foo` set to `nil`. Why don't I get an error?

```
# migration
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :foo

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

# post creation, no error ???
Post.create!(name: 'a post', foo: 'a_string')

# post has nil value in foo
Post.first
#=> Post id: 1, name: "a post", foo: nil, ...
```

Actually, I wanted to write a failing test for the Post, and then I would change foo to be an enum to make the test pass. I was surprised that the test did not raise an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a "feature" of the db. Rails at this point doesn't know about the type of the attribute. If you want it to only accept integers, you can use `validates_numericality_of :foo`.

If you want your test to fail while it's not an enum, you could do something like

`expect { subject.foo = 'invalid value' }.to raise_exception(ArgumentError)`

that way it will fail as long as it's not an enum.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want it to only accept integers. I want to write a failing test (TDD) to make the field an enum. I could check that the field after creation is the expected value, but is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but if it should be an enum, you can use the `ActiveRecord::Enum` feature. That way it won't accept any invalid numeric values but will still be settable from strings and ordinals.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Enum feature - but how do I write a test that fails first, and then add the enum line in the model to make it pass?

Comment: @Anand I understood now, added a sentence about that to my answer.